# Is it possible to adjust textview with small picture inside it?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitextview

I moved from android to Swift. In android we could assign a drawable to the left or right of the text, we could do this in XML.

for example this XML for a textView with picture on the left:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="This is test text view and it is showing"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/myImage" />
```

so the image "myImage.png" will be same as the picture below.

I wonder if there is something similar in swift for ios ?

[image: Android]

Comment: You could make a custom control, but this does not exist by default within UIKit.  There is a text field, a text view, and an image view.  Combine them however you want to your heart's content.

Comment: in interface builder, u can assign background and image to the textView, i wanna specify that this background should be to the left side of the text. @nhgrif

Comment: As I just stated, this is not possible with the default controls.

Comment: But remember in IB you can pin the image to the text, even if they are separate items, they would function the same.

Comment: yeah i found out that this is the best answer for this in ios, you may add it as an answer @Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode Interface Builder, you can't really do that with one item. The best solution is to create a textView *and* an imageView, then pin the two together with aligning and margins in auto layout.